# Apache2 permission denied on Ubuntu

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

My `apache2.conf`:

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}


PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/amiroof/Projects/amiroo54.github.io/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

The `000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/amiroof/Projects/amiroo54.github.io/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
</VirtualHost>
```

`apachectl -S`:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
Group: name="www-data" id=33 not_used
```

`error.log` (at least the relevant part of it):

```
[Mon Nov 06 20:07:56.089265 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13431:tid 140277191919488] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 06 20:07:56.089426 2023] [core:notice] [pid 13431:tid 140277191919488] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Nov 06 20:12:46.341517 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13431:tid 140277191919488] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Mon Nov 06 20:12:46.416245 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13960:tid 140063562352512] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 06 20:12:46.416399 2023] [core:notice] [pid 13960:tid 140063562352512] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Nov 06 20:16:26.580115 2023] [core:error] [pid 13962:tid 140063545972416] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:52216] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/amiroof/Projects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Mon Nov 06 20:16:26.749283 2023] [core:error] [pid 13962:tid 140063529187008] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:52216] AH00035: access to /favicon.ico denied (filesystem path '/home/amiroof/Projects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost/
[Mon Nov 06 20:17:47.267389 2023] [core:error] [pid 13961:tid 140063545972416] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:33772] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/amiroof/Projects') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
[Mon Nov 06 20:18:05.698161 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13960:tid 140063562352512] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Mon Nov 06 20:18:05.796597 2023] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14406:tid 140167944808320] AH00489: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I tried every solution I found on the web but nothing works. I tried setting the permissions (`root`, `home`, `user`, `Projects`, `amiroo54.github.io` directories) to `755`, I tried `sudo chown amiroof:www-data`, I tried `setfacl -m u:www-data;rx`, but none of them worked. I am using Ubuntu 23.10, Apache version 2.4.57.

Comment: Do you use directories under a user's home folder for Apache. You will have endless problems with permissions and security. Apache should only use directories that are secured for Apache.

Answer (score -1):

You should change the owner or the permissions of `/home/amiroof/Projects`. Try this to change the owner of the directory (don't forget the `-R`):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/amiroof/Projects
```

As [@Thomas Ward](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491742/apache2-permission-denied-on-ubuntu/1491747#comment2613323_1491742) said, with the above solution the user `amiroof` will not be able to edit the files. If you want the user to be able to edit these file, you can do something like this:

```
sudo chown -R amiroof:www-data /home/amiroof/Projects
sudo chmod -R 775 /home/amiroof/Projects
```

There are other ways to do this better, but it really depends on your workflow and exactly what you are trying to achieve. Is a OK solution to use on your dev machine, but if you are planning to deploy it on a production server, please don't.

Comment: This will prevent User from editing the files by changing owner.  Which I don't think OP wants.

Comment: @ThomasWard yep, I updated my answer... still not the best solution IMO, but I hope it helps the OP.

Comment: Although you are technically correct, this would be a very bad practice. Only use directories allocated and secured for Apache.

Comment: @JohnHanley I agree, but I am trying to answer what the OP is asking. To me it looks like he is just looking for a quick fix on his dev machine, but I may be wrong. In my answer I explicitly said that it shouldn't be used in a production environment.